# hide Excel tab from Javascript code

Tags: javascript, excel, jscript, wsh

How can I hide an Excel tab programmatically through Javascript.
ExcelSheetName.Visible=False doesn't seem to work. I've googled a lot but yet not received the right solution. How to do that ?

Comment: So my requirement is that out of the 2 tabs, I want 2 display only 1 Excel tab to the users. So, I don't think the above code would work.

Comment: There are 3 valid values for the `Visible` property of a worksheet.
xlSheetVisible = -1, xlSheetHidden = 0, xlSheetVeryHidden = 2

Answer (score 1):

To hide an Excel sheet, set the `Visible` property of the corresponding `Worksheet` object to `0` or `false`.
For example, if you have an Excel file with two sheets named *Sheet1* and *Sheet2*, the following code will open this file with the *Sheet1* hidden:

```
var objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
objExcel.Visible = true;
objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Book1.xlsx");

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = false;
// You can aslo use this --
//objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = 0; // xlSheetHidden
```

> So I said as u pointed out. This is my code:
>
> ```
> var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
> var xl = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
> xl.Visible = true;
> var wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(fso.GetAbsolutePathName("Temp.csv"));
> xl.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Visible = false;
> ```
>
> But on doing so, I get the error as Unable to set the Visible property of the Worksheet class. Any clue what could be the possible error ?

The error is because CSV files have only one tab in Excel, and you can't hide the only visible tab. At least 1 tab must always be visible.

Comment: So I said as u pointed out. This is my code:- var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var xl = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
xl.Visible = true;
var wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(fso.GetAbsolutePathName("Temp.csv"));
xl.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Visible = false; But on doing so, I get the error as Unable to set the Visible property of the Worksheet class. Any clue what could be the possible error ?